# Multiple popups with buttons

Tags: javascript

I'd like to make multiple popups which shows individually when each buttons click.

Here is what I've done so far

[image: Javascript]

```html
<body>
<button id="popup_btn" class="popup_btn" type="button"> Hi </button>   
          
<div id="popup" class="popup_wrap">
  <div class="popup_content">
    <p> Hi</p>
    <button id="popup_close" class="close"> close </button>
  </div>
</div> 

<button id="popup_btn" class="popup_btn" type="button"> History </button>   
          
<div id="popup" class="popup_wrap">
  <div class="popup_content">
    <p> Hi</p>
    <button id="popup_close" class="close"> close </button>
  </div>
</div> 

<button id="popup_btn" class="popup_btn" type="button"> Skill </button>   
          
<div id="popup" class="popup_wrap">
  <div class="popup_content">
    <p> Hi</p>
    <button id="popup_close" class="close"> close </button>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post CODE instead of PICTURES of code! Visit the [help] to see why. Also what is your question? You need to use CLASS instead of ID if you have multiple popups doing the same. IDs need to be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You do not need to loop when using jQuery to assign event handlers to a button. Give it a class and have the button figure out where it is
2. give the buttons a data attribute to tell it what to open

```js
$(function() {
  $(".popup_btn").on("click",function() {
    $("#"+$(this).data("div")).toggle();
  });
  $(".popup_close").on("click",function() {
    $(this).closest("div.popup_wrap").hide();
  });
  
});
```

```css
.popup_wrap {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button data-div="popup1" id="popup_btn1" class="popup_btn" type="button">Hi</button>

  <div id="popup1" class="popup_wrap">
    <div class="popup_content">
      <p>Hi</p>
      <button class="popup_close" class="close">close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button data-div="popup2" id="popup_btn2" class="popup_btn" type="button">History</button>

  <div id="popup2" class="popup_wrap">
    <div class="popup_content">
      <p>Hi</p>
      <button class="popup_close" class="close">close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button data-div="popup3" id="popup_btn3" class="popup_btn" type="button">Skill</button>

  <div id="popup3" class="popup_wrap">
    <div class="popup_content">
      <p>Hi</p>
      <button class="popup_close" class="close">close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Oh...Thank you T^T but the popup box didn't close;;;;;;;;;;; T^T Actually, I posted the javascript and css but there was an error so that I could add screenshot;;;

Comment: the code I posted closes the divs when close is clicked